# Reading a file for a npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have created a npm package named test_package_cat, which is supposed to read a json file (info.json) at the beginning.
Thus, index.js (main entry) and info.json are at the same level.

When I run the index.js locally, I can read the file.

either:

```
fs.readFileSync('info.json')
```

or

```
fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'info.json')
```

works fine.

However, when I have another program, a **React** page,that uses the package, it fails to read the json file.

```
 cat = require('test_package_cat')
 cat.meow()
```

When I run index.js locally, if I console.log(__dirname), it gives me C://......../myProject. 
However, when running the React app, console.log(__dirname) just prints "/" and when I try to print directories/files, it shows nothing.

How can I make the my npm package to read info.json file?

**Edit**: After more searching, I managed to get it working by doing:

```
let info = require('./info.json')
console.log(JSON.stringify(info))
```

but would still like to know how to do it using "readFile" way.

Comment: The most useful thing you can do is link us to a github repository containing the code you're trying to run. It would also be helpful to know what you mean by "fails to read the json file". Are you using a build tool like webpack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs` is only available in the Node runtime environment. It isn't available in a browser's JavaScript runtime environment. I'm surprised you haven't encountered an error to that effect.

Comment: so what do i do? how do i package code that needs to read a file in such a way that it can run in the browser?

Comment: I know this isn't an answer you want to hear, but generally speaking you don't. You don't package code that uses Node-only APIs as part of a front end project (the exception being dev dependencies which aren't loaded at runtime). 

You could try to find a way to hack it to make it work. For example, you could create your own `fs` object that implements the APIs you need at declare it to the global context before the library is loaded. That would fix it temporarily, but it would be very brittle. There might be existing libraries that do this, but I don't have any recommendations.

Comment: However, the "make your own `fs` idea" isn't really realistic. The reason why the API doesn't exist in browsers is because browsers don't have access to the local filesystem. The vast majority of functions on the `fs` object are things that interact with the filesystem.

Comment: I asked my question as a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69341534/npm-package-that-needs-to-read-a-local-file