# npm package that needs to read a local file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm building an ES module that needs to run in both the browser and in Node.js through the command line and it needs to read a file containing data in the package. Imagine an English dictionary package, where `english_words.txt` is a regular word list and `index.js` looks like this

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)); // There's no __dirname in ES modules
const dictionaryFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'english_words.txt')
const englishWords = fs.readFileSync(dictionaryFile).split('\n')

export const isEnglishWord = word => englishWords.includes(word)
```

My issue is I don't know how to read the txt file in such a way that can work in the browser as well. And if someone is using my package with a JS builder/bundler, how would that work?

Comment: You have to read the file with a HTTP request in a browser without bundler, e.g. `fetch`. A bundler can bundle local files with `import` / `require`.

Comment: @jabaa how can I fetch something if I don't know how users of my package are going to be hosting it?

Comment: You could set a fixed relative path.